# Windows 7 freezing while using Skype, refreezes after a minute

Tags: freeze, skype

About three weeks ago, my laptop started to randomly freeze when using Skype or listening to music on YouTube.

I use Windows 7 Home and all kinds of software.

Yesterday, I reinstalled my OS and got Windows 7 Professional (not upgrade, a clean installation, so no other applications installed) and when I Skype, it still freezes – though less often then normally.

I also tried to install an older version of Skype but the problem persists. Do you think it could be a hardware problem? Since there is no error message after it refreezes after a minute or so. I don't even know how to analyse what goes wrong.

Please ask if you need more info about my laptop.

EDIT: more info
  a lot for your help. I cleaned the vents but it did not help. Also, today, I reinstalled audio drivers since that might have been the problem, as Rob suggested. Again, without success.

Do you think there might be a problem with the connection to the internet which would actually be able to freez my laptop? What I did to test that: go to youtube and have several videos downloaded to cache. play all the videos at the same time + watch a movie from external hard drive + browse photos from external hard drive = no freezing. VS. open a youtube video and let it play before it all is downloaded to cache => freez.

My connection: university wireless internet connection... maybe I should try to connect to the internet via LAN cable?

Another explanation that I can think of is that I moved from Europe to the US. Do you think that might have an influence? I doubt that...

SOLUTION
Ok, after using cable to connect to the internet, the computer did not freeze. So I reinstalled my wireless drivers (Atheros AR9285 drivers) and it seems working!! :) I will keep you posted if it really helped.

Comment: Maybe an issue with audio mixing?

Comment: Have you cleaned your input and exhaust vents recently?

Comment: Check vents for dust, as techie007 suggested. It's probably a heating issue.

Comment: Bob: if you solved the problem, please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. I also merged your two accounts, so you won't need to get permission to make edits now.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Ok, after using cable to connect to the internet, the computer did not freeze. So I reinstalled my wireless drivers (Atheros AR9285 drivers) and it seems working!! :)